# Text is seen through dropdown menu

Tags: css

I have placed a text (part of page content) over primary menu bar (it's not nested inside menu bar, just adjusted by margin values to look that way).

Happened that when I hover a mouse over another - secondary - menu located just above on the screen, the text is also over its dropdown menu.[please see a screenshot pic where I highlighted a problem by red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uf2D.jpg)

What I'm actually trying to do is to assign different z-indexes for primary menu (to be below the text) and secondary menu (to have its dropdown above the text). So far unfortunately none of the efforts helped. Wonder can it be because both of menus are nested inside header thus inherit its z-index values, and I cannot make them have different z-index? Or maybe I didn't find right selector for the items I'm tweaking?

I will be very grateful if anyone can advise!

Link to website with the issue: https://petshophaus.com/

Comment: Please add relevant pieces of code here

Comment: @Realina your site is in maintenance mode.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just deactivated.

Comment: It looks like the offending text is only visible when the user is ordering things. Since we're not going to do that, can you make a [mcve] that already has the text showing?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<p>` to menu-primary as the last child. CSS for `<p>`:

```
margin-top: 2%;
color: #442929;
float: right;
```